# How to store value in variable with .load();

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, load

I want to compare two variables, `oldRefresh` and `newRefresh`. the `oldRefresh`'s value in an input so easily storing it in `oldRefresh` by typing `var oldRefresh= $('#oldrefresh').val();`

but the `newRefresh`, is hard to get it, I need to get it from another file with `.load();`

this is the code:

```
var oldRefresh= $('#oldrefresh').val();

setInterval(function ()
{
    $('#noti_number').load('include/js_notification_count.php?n=".$_SESSION['username']."');
    });
}, 5000);
```

I tried this:

```
var newRefresh = setInterval(function ()
{
    $('#noti_number').load('include/js_notification_count.php?n=".$_SESSION['username']."');
    });
}, 5000); 
alert(newRefresh);
```

the result of this is `2` when the result of the load it should be `0`.

so I tried this

```
setInterval(function ()
{
    var newRefresh = $('#noti_number').load('include/js_notification_count.php?n=".$_SESSION['username']."');
    });
    alert(newRefresh);
}, 5000);
```

the result of this is `[object Object]`. I don't get it. how do I get the `load` value into a variable?

Comment: Don't use `.load()`. It's meant for replacing a DOM element's contents with the file loaded by Ajax. Use [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) instead.

Comment: Also `load()` returns a jQuery object, not what I think you intended.

Comment: Just a comment, somewhat unrelated to your posted question: you might wanted to reconsider passing `n=".$_SESSION['username']."` back to your `js_notification_count.php` script and instead just access your `$_SESSION['username]` on the PHP side. That could make your client-side and server-side logic a little cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery load is replacing the object with the information returned from your js_notification_count.php file.  You could add .text() or change load function like:

```
setInterval(function () {
   $('#noti_number').load('include/js_notification_count.php?n=<?=$_SESSION['username']?>', function(response, status, xhr) {
         newRefresh = response;
         alert(newRefresh);
      }
   });
}, 5000);
```

I would use ajax instead though (if you don't need noti_number to have the returned response) like:

```
setInterval(function () {
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET", //Change to whatever method type you are using on your page
      url: "include/js_notification_count.php",
      data: { n: "<?=$_SESSION['username']?>" }
   }).done(function(result) {
      newRefresh = result;
      alert(newRefresh);
   });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: give me an example on .text().

Comment: Try using one of the other 2 examples here.  .text() would be just after the .load(url).text(), but not sure that will be reliable.  The other functions are called after the call completes.

Comment: n request didn't work, in ajax, I change the session with my name `n: 'AbdullahSalma'` so the result should be `60`. in `include/js_notification_count.php` I type `if(empty($_G['n'])){echo "empty";}else{..}` the alert show me `empty`.

Answer (score -1):

if you do this you should be able to compare the values:

```
$('#noti_number').load(
   'include/js_notification_count.php?n=".$_SESSION['username']."',
   function(aData) {
      //Do your comparison here.
   }
)
```

The data passed back should be the response from the server.

Comment: I compare `oldRefresh` with what? aData?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. aData is the exact response from the server as text string